# React Images flickering instead of moving to first place

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am learning react and I am trying to make my porfolio website with it. I need someone to explain how this works. I want to make a simple carousel spinning automaticaly and when an element leaves the viewport to just send it to beginning, but what happens when that element leaves the viewport all of the elements just start flickering because state is changing and re renders happen a lot and i dont know what to do.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import html from "./img/html-5.svg";
import css from "./img/css-3.svg";
import javascript from "./img/javascript.svg";

import "./Skills.css";

import SkillsIcon from "./SkillsIcon";

class Skills extends Component {
  static defaultProps = {
    icons: [
      html,
      css,
      javascript,
    ],
  };
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      pos: new Array(this.props.icons.length).fill(0),
      items: [...document.getElementsByClassName("SkillsIcon")],
      queue: [],
      icons: this.props.icons,
    };

    this.spinElement = this.spinElement.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    setInterval(this.spinElement, 10);
    console.log("did mount");
    this.setState(st => {
      return {
        items: [...st.items, ...document.getElementsByClassName("SkillsIcon")],
      };
    });
  }

  spinElement() {
    this.setState(st => {
      let newPos = st.pos.map((item, i) => {
        return (st.pos[i] = item + 0.1);
      });
      let toExactPos = st.items.map(item => {
        return item.offsetLeft;
      });
      let exactPos = st.pos.map((item, i) => {
        return newPos[i] + toExactPos[i];
      });
      return {
        pos: newPos,
        itemExact: exactPos,
      };
    });
  }
  // Render one by one
  // First element out of the box by - (clientWidth / items.length) pixels
  renderElement() {
    let itemSpacing = document.body.clientWidth / this.state.items.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < this.state.icons.length; i++) {
      if (this.state.items[i]) {
        let rect = this.state.items[i].getBoundingClientRect();
        if (Math.floor(rect.x) > document.body.clientWidth - 150) {
          let last = this.state.icons.pop();
          if (last) {
            this.state.icons.unshift(last);
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return (
      <div className='SkillsAll'>
        {this.state.icons.map((icon, i) => {
          return (
            <SkillsIcon
              className='SkillsIcon'
              src={icon}
              alt={icon}
              style={{
                transform: `translateX(${this.state.pos[i]}px)`,
                margin: `${itemSpacing / this.}px`,
              }}
            />
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }

  render() {
    return <div className='Skills'>{this.renderElement()}</div>;
  }
}

export default Skills;
```

Child component is render only component, nothing much to see.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./SkillsIcon.css";

class SkillsIcon extends Component {a
  render() {
    return (
      <img
        className={this.props.className}
        src={this.props.src}
        alt={this.props.alt}
        style={this.props.style}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default SkillsIcon;
```

What do I do, how do I stop the re rendering? Can redux help with this? And how do I pop an element out of render and return it to beginning without causing the flicker?

Comment: You trigger a setInterval that calls spinElement every 10 milliseconds and spinElement mutates the state, I think that combo is your problem

Comment: I need that setInterval to move elements. Whatever i do state has to be changed and it will cause a re render.

Comment: I think the problem is this line `return <div className='Skills'>{this.renderElement()}</div>;` try calling it like this instead `return <div className='Skills'>{this.renderElement}</div>;`

Comment: I must call that function in order to render elements, otherwise it will return nothing in render.